# C sizeof calculation run-time, compile-time

Tags: c, sizeof

[image]

I think pointer size can be calculated in compile-time because you should specify 32bit compile or 64bit compile at compile-time.

But in that case, why sizeof calculated in run-time?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

In wikipedia it says, sizeof caculate flexible array in run-time, most in compile-time.

Comment: Both examples shown here `sizeof(int *)` and `sizeof(int[10])` are known at compile time.

Comment: The first example would make more sense if the value `10` was replaced with a variable whose value was read at run-time.

Comment: And the `sizeof(x)` in the first example makes no sense, `sizeof` of a pointer is the size of the *pointer itself* not whatever memory it might point to. So wherever you got the slide from, I would say it's a bad source that you shouldn't rely on to much. Not to mention that the correct [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format for `size_t` (which is the type of the result of `sizeof`) is `%zu`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The only case where `sizeof` is computed at run time (AFIAK) is with [variable length arrays (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I may ask to professor.

Comment: Instead of making an image, please make code formatted as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both of these cases the result of `sizeof` is known at compile time.  In the first case it is the size of an `int *` and in the second case it is the size of an `int` array of length 10.

The slide seems to think that `sizeof` in the first case will give you the the amount of memory allocated, however this is not true.  The user must keep track of how much space was allocated to ensure that the bounds are not exceeded.

The only time `sizeof` is calculated at run time is for a variable length array, for example:

```
int x = foo();
int arr[x];
printf("size=%zu\n", sizeof(arr));
```

This behavior is dictated by section 6.5.3.4p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The `sizeof` operator  yields  the  size  (in  bytes)  of  its 
>   operand,  which  may  be  an expression or the parenthesized name of a
>   type.  The size is determined from the type of the operand.  The
>   result is an integer.  If the type of the operand is a variable length
>   array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not
>   evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

Comment: The standard does not say either expression is calculated at compile time or run time. It says the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated unless its type is a variable length array, in which case it is evaluated. That evaluation could be implemented at compile time, if the compiler recognizes enough information to do so. Conversely, the size of the non-variable-length type could be computed at run-time. (For example, for `sizeof(int [3][4][5])`, the compiler would not violate the standard by multiplying 3, 4, and 5 by the size of `int` at run time. The fact we expect this not to occur is…

Comment: … a matter of compiler quality and optimization, not standard conformance.